# Routing Data Source by using Abstract Routing Data Source

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, hibernate-mapping

I am creation project for Routing Data Source by using Abstract Routing Data Source . While deploying in wildfly jboss , Getting Following error , My bean is not crating , showing exception while crating Session Factory .

"{\"JBAS014671: Failed services\" => {\"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Final_login_details\" => \"org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Final_login_details: Failed to start service
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
    Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError\"}}"

configuration file :-

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
          class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
          p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties"/>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.rss.setting.RoutingDataSource">  
 <property name="targetDataSources">
   <map key-type="com.rss.setting.DbType">
     <entry key="MASTERS" value-ref="dataSourceMaster"/>
     <entry key="TARIFF" value-ref="dataSourceTariff"/>     
     <entry key="SETTING" value-ref="dataSourceSetting"/>
   </map>
 </property>
 <property name="defaultTargetDataSource" ref="dataSourceMaster"/>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSourceMaster" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">  
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" /> 
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/> 
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>   
</bean> 
<bean id="dataSourceTariff" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">  
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" /> 
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.usernameTarif}"/> 
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.passwordTarif}"/>    
</bean> 

<bean id="dataSourceSetting" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">  
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" /> 
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.usernameSetting}"/> 
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.passwordSetting}"/>     
</bean> 

 <context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties"/>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
     class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

    <property name="dataSource">
      <ref bean="dataSource"/>
    </property>



    <property name="hibernateProperties">
       <props>
         <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</prop>
           <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
       <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop> 
            <prop key="format_sql">true</prop>

       </props>
    </property>
    </bean>
```

Please assist me , my bean is not able to create . I am not able to trace the error .
Thanks 
Rohit

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then improve your question. For starters add the *full* stack trace instead of a snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Bean Crated Success fully . It was coming because my bean was referring null value "com.rss.setting.RoutingDataSource" in this class